# Elastic Search 8 - interaction through the nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-8

I'm trying to implement previous ES 5.6 logic for 8+ version. I need to go thought the nested property and do some checks. Any ideas how to do that?
mapping:

```
 --- some_propetry one
 ----- nested property
 -------nested property
 ---------- boolean property1
 ---------- boolean property2
 ---------- long property3
 ---------- long property4
```

I need to go through propery1-4 for each document and do some inline painless script filtering.
Before it was easy, with params._source. But now, there's no more access to params._source from query scripts. How could it be achieved? Iteration through doc[] doesn't help, it lost order of nested properties and mix them inside the parent one

More detailed with structure and examples explained here:
---------- boolean property1

Comment: more detailed issue explanation with structures is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76907006/elastic-search-8-painless-script-filtering-issue-no-access-to-params-source-v

Comment: I shared an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76907006/elastic-search-8-painless-script-filtering-issue-no-access-to-params-source-v